# Reactive Kafka not working

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am trying out an simple reactive-kafka program which reads and writes to Kafka. It starts up but does nothing even when I am publishing messages to the input topic.

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("main")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

val kafkaUrl: String = "localhost:9092"

val producerSettings = ProducerSettings(system, new ByteArraySerializer, new StringSerializer)
  .withBootstrapServers(kafkaUrl)
val consumerSettings = ConsumerSettings(system, new ByteArrayDeserializer, new StringDeserializer,
  Set("inputTopic"))
  .withBootstrapServers(kafkaUrl)
  .withGroupId("group1")
  .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")

val flow: RunnableGraph[Control] = Consumer.committableSource(consumerSettings.withClientId("client1"))
  .map { msg =>
    println("msg = " + msg)
    Producer.Message(new ProducerRecord[Array[Byte], String]("test.topic2", msg.value), msg.committableOffset)
  }
  .to(Producer.commitableSink(producerSettings))
flow.run()
```

It just stays there forever. Any tips on debugging why this is not working?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm experiencing something similar.

Comment: Nope, I did not. Haven't looked at this recently though.